# File loading too slow! (C++)

Tags: c++, file, stream, directx, loading

I'm trying to write a model file loader for a DirectX Engine...

It looks like this at the moment:

```
irrFireMesh* irrFireDevice::loadModel(char* filename)
{

ifstream in_stream;
string line;
in_stream.open(filename);
int vertexCount = 0;
int vCount = -1;

irrFireMesh* triangleMesh = new irrFireMesh();
irrFireVertex* vertices;
unsigned long* indices;
irrFireMaterial* mat;

while(getline(in_stream, line, '\n'))
{
    std::string word;
    std::stringstream stream(line);
    std::string param[15];
    int i = 0;
    while( getline(stream, word, ' ') ){
    param[i] = word;
    i++;
    }

    then = timeGetTime();
    if(param[0] == "newbuf")
    {
        vertexCount = StI(param[1]);
        vertices = new irrFireVertex[vertexCount];
        if(!vertices) return NULL;
        indices = new unsigned long[vertexCount];
        if(!indices) return NULL;
        mat = new irrFireMaterial(this);
        cout<<"Begin buffer width "<<vertexCount<<" vertices"<<endl;
        vCount = -1;
        continue;
    }
    if(vertexCount <= 0) continue;

    if(param[0] == "endbuf")
    {
        irrFireMeshBuffer* mbuf = new irrFireMeshBuffer();

        mbuf->vertexCount = vertexCount;
        mbuf->indexCount = vertexCount;
        mbuf->vertices = vertices;
        mbuf->indices = indices;
        mat->INITIALIZE();
        mbuf->material = mat;
        triangleMesh->addMeshBuffer(mbuf);
        vertexCount = 0;
        cout<<"End buffer width "<<vCount+1<<" vertices."<<endl;
        continue;
    }

    if(param[0] == "v")
    {
        vCount++;
        vertices[vCount].position = D3DXVECTOR3(StF(param[1]), StF(param[3]), StF(param[2]));
        vertices[vCount].color = D3DXVECTOR4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        vertices[vCount].uv = D3DXVECTOR2((StF(param[1]) + StF(param[3]))*10.0f, StF(param[2])*10.0f);
        indices[vCount] = vCount;
        if((vCount+1) % 3 == 0)
        {
            D3DXVECTOR3 NRML, D1, D2;
            D1 = vertices[vCount-2].position - vertices[vCount-1].position;
            D2 = vertices[vCount-1].position - vertices[vCount].position;
            D3DXVec3Cross(&NRML, &D1, &D2);
            D3DXVec3Normalize(&NRML, &NRML);

            vertices[vCount-2].normal = NRML;
            vertices[vCount-1].normal = NRML;
            vertices[vCount].normal = NRML;
        }
        continue;
    }
}

in_stream.close();
return triangleMesh;
}
```

The model file for a triangle would look like this:

```
newbuf 3
v 0.0 0.0 0.0
v 0.5 1.0 0.0
v 1.0 0.0 0.0
endbuf
```

It works like it is supposed to, but way too slow, when loading complex models...
Could you point out the bottleneck to me and point out to a faster way of solving this?

EDIT:
Ok, I benchmarked the time needed by some functions and it turned out, that the parsing part

```
if(param[0] == "v")
{
.
.
.
}
```

takes about 4000 ms in total, when parsing 23400 vertices. But when I replace

```
vertices[vCount].position = D3DXVECTOR3(StF(param[1]), StF(param[3]), StF(param[2]));
```

with

```
vertices[vCount].position = D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
```

it only takes about 300 ms in total. So the performance killer seems to be StF() which looks like this:

```
float StF(string in)
{
stringstream mystr("");
mystr<<in;
float res = 0;
mystr>>res;
return res;
}
```

Any ideas, how to do it right? Because this is obviously too slow...

Comment: There's a bunch of things that are at least questionable. `char const* filename`. Too much use of `new`. Use of `new[]` (should be std::vector). Use of raw pointers, your code leaks memory in multiple cases. Checking the result of `new` for null, it will throw an exception. None of this is a performance killer though. Try to add 'ios_base::binary' to the `open()` call, this will avoid some unnecessary conversions. Then, create a benchmark program where you only load the lines of the file and publish the timing here along with the timing of your current code, because what is "way too slow"?

Comment: Okay, I'll keep that in mind, but wasn't std::vector kind of slow for such things? I heard something like that... I loaded a model with 23400 vertexes and measured the time of some parts that could kill performance: getline(...) needed 778 ms in total (0.03 ms avg.), the parameter split part needed 1164 ms in total (0.05 ms avg.) and the parameter parsing part needed 4816 ms in total (0.20 ms avg.) I expected the parameter split part to be way more expensive... I will start another test and measure the time needed by the StF() function...

Comment: Also, are you compiling with optimizations turned on (e.g. release mode)?

Comment: std::vector is not "slow for such things". Operations have a certain complexity, but those have little to no overhead over dynamically allocated arrays. In your case, it would make a difference between code that is broken in some cases and code that works reliably though, so until you really know that std::vector is not suitable, use it.

Comment: Concerning StF(), there's a bunch of places where you just throw away performance. Firstly, you copy the string by passing it to the function. This can be a dynamic allocation for something you intend to throw away afterwards anyway. Then, you initialize the stringstream with an empty string (why?) and then stream in the parameter, which will effectively copy the data once more. Instead, init with the parameter. Then, you init the float to zero, why? That said, you don't even verify that parsing the float succeeded. Lastly, StF is the same but only almost as good as boost::lexical_cast.

Comment: It's pretty old code I copy and pasted somewhere a while ago and never really think about again... These are things you don't really care about, when you just want to get it working and aren't worrying about performance. But now it got a problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overhead of the "new" commands depends on how many "newbuf" sections are encountered, but it seems to me that you need the new commands, as you need to save each array.  Converting to vector might not be an option depending on whether or not you can modify the mesh class.

If you have access to a profiler, that would be good to use to verify where it is spending its time.  It can show you which lines of code are worse than others.  Many times, this should be your first step when attempting to optimize; often, you just end up guessing wrong if you just try to eyeball it.

Reading in text format is going to be slower.  Also, conversion from string to float takes a bit of time, as well as the new commands.  You probably could read in each "newbuf" section as a an array of strings, and multithread the processing (where the new and other processing is handled in parallel).  You have to synchronize things before you add the arrays back into the destination mesh.

Comment: Thanks! Multithreading it seams like a good idea! I'll try that! I now threw out the getline() and the param[] part and ended up with something like this:

while(!in_stream.eof())
 {
        char prefix[10] = {0};
        in_stream >> prefix;

        switch (prefix[0]) {
            case 'v' : {
                 float x, y, z;
                 in_stream >> x >> y >> z;
                 vCount++;